# How to put a matrix of images?

Tags: graphics

I´m trying to place 4 images as a matrix 2 x 2

I´m having trouble with the first row....

What am I doing wrong?

I have read that subcaption package (or similar name)....is a suitable package

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      \includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg} \\
      {\small ''iteraciones máximas de BT''=20} &  \\
      {\small ''Periodo de Tenencia en Lista Tabú''=2}&  \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What do you recommend me?

What´s the best practise/way in these cases.

The simu.jpg is a normal image [SIMU.JPG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n110u1t18gspla/simu.jpg)

---

With These technique I obtained this [image: example a row with 4 images], without any problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a small problem that the image touches the upper line. Some PDF readers does not show the upper line above the images depending on the view scale settings.

The following example defines macro `\addheight` that increases the height of
the image box (adds some white space above the image). The amount can be configured via the optional argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\addheight}[2][.5ex]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+(#1)\relax]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \addheight{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg}} &
      \addheight{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg}} \\
      \small ``row 2, column 1'' &  ``row 2, column 2'' \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I tried to compile your code, but I obtain the same message that with my code... http://sensa.square7.ch/gdfgdfg.jpg

Comment: @MikaIke: Compile with `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. For `latex`/`dvips`/`ps2pdf` the `.jpg` files should be converted to `.eps` (e.g. [`jpeg2eps`](http://rses.anu.edu.au/~andy/jpeg2eps/))

Comment: Thank you! Yes You´re right with PDF-Latex my initial purpose also runs well!! but... I need to use LATEX bacause in the same document I have pstricks figures. What´s the solution?

Comment: @MikaIke: There are many ways, convert `.png` and `.jpeg` to `.eps`, use XeLaTeX, or `auto-pst-pdf` with pdflatex, ... too many to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 14):

So long as the images all have the same dimensions, you can do with a `tabular`; I defined an auxiliary `\subf` command for the picture and the subcaption, but just for keeping things properly segregated. You can add any number of `\\` commands in the caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
  {\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  #1\\#2
  \end{tabular}}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
     {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
     {``Periodo de Tenencia \\ en Lista Tabú''$=2$}
\\
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
     {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
     {``Periodo de Tenencia \\ en Lista Tabú''$=2$}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If some space is wanted between the tabular rule and the image, here's a possible way: create a fake first line and back up vertically.

The code is exactly the same as before, but the definition of `\subf` changes into

```
\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
  {\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
   \mbox{}\\[-\ht\strutbox]
   #1\\#2
   \end{tabular}}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answer but as Heiko Oberdiek pointed out, the overlap of the edges of the graphic element and the edge of the table create a rather awkward end result. Isn't there a (a more robust) way to inherently add space between a graphic element within a tabular environment?

Comment: @Euryris Of course there is; I'll add it.

Comment: @egreg I tried your code, (changing the source ...pdf for the simu.jpg) and reach... this error (the same with my purpose and the Heiko´purpose)   http://sensa.square7.ch/gdfgdfg45.jpg

Comment: @MikaIke You're compiling with `latex` instead of `pdflatex`; the former can't deal with JPG.

Comment: @egreg Yes, your´re rigght like Heiko said me the same. The problem is taht in the same document I need tuo use LATESX, bacause I have pstricks pictures. What´s the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Part 1 (figures):

Have you tried something like:

```
\documentclass{whatever}
...
\newsavebox{<boxname>}
\setbox\<boxname>=\hbox{
\includegraphics[<options>]{<filename}}
} 

\begin{document}
...
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
{\usebox{\<boxname>}}
...
\end{tabular}
...
\end{document}
```

You can resize boxes using the `\resizebox` or manually with arguments of `includegraphics`.

---

Part 2 (text):

You can also use `\hbox` (this is in the standard LaTeX engine, no package required), or
`\pbox{<size of box>}{<text, argument, figure, you name it>}` (this will require `\usepackage{pbox}` to function, and perhaps a small update of your TeX/package distribution).

`\pbox` also allows you to use linebreaks within the environment:

```
\pbox{<size of box>}{<text, argument, figure, you name it> \\
                     <more text, arguments, figures, etc.>    
                    }
```

(If you decide this is prettier.)

---

These are pretty robust and impractical solutions to put figure (option 1) and text (option 2) into floats (floats are figures, tikzpictures, and I'm pretty sure this works too for tables).

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  \pbox{6cm}{\vspace{5ex} \includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg}} & \pbox{6cm}    {\vspace{5ex} \includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg}} \\
  {\pbox{6cm}{\vspace{.25ex}\small ''iteraciones máximas de BT''=20\vspace{5ex}}}     &       {\pbox{6cm}{\vspace{5ex}\small ''Periodo de Tenencia en Lista Tabú''=2\vspace{5ex}}} \\
 &  \\
  \hline
  \pbox{6cm}{\vspace{5ex} \includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg}} & \pbox{6cm}    {\vspace{5ex} \includegraphics[width=60mm]{simu.jpg}} \\
  {\pbox{6cm}{\vspace{5ex}\small ''iteraciones máximas de BT''=20\vspace{5ex}}} &   {\pbox{6cm}{\vspace{.25ex}\small ''Periodo de Tenencia en Lista Tabú''=2 \vspace{5ex}}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here you can see that you can control the height to whatever length you want (using `vspace`) and the width, using `pbox`. Is this what you want?

Comment: but.., I have use that with other smaller graphics and... good results!! ... with width I would must control the width of the image

Comment: There's no need to use a `figure` environment for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: I just used `figure` as an example. I'll edit to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: is possible a minimal example?. I think that I have view in any post any similar to what I want, but.. I can´t find it.