# \hline not covering the whole of the cell

Tags: tables, graphics

I am using the answer shown here provided by egreg:

[How to put a matrix of images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173820/how-to-put-a-matrix-of-images)

However I would like a line between the graph and the caption under the graph. I tried doing it by modifying the `\subf` function by placing an `\hline` between `#1` and `#2`. This seems to work before you add the images. But when the images are added there is a gap between the hline above the caption and the vertical lines of the surrounding matrix (see image below)?

How can this gaps be removed?

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
{\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
#1\ \hline \#2
\end{tabular}}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``Periodo de Tenencia \\ en Lista Tabú''$=2$}
\\
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``Periodo de Tenencia \\ en Lista Tabú''$=2$}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The gap is most likely due to `|c|c|` from the outer tabular, you've got extra spacing there between the vertical lines and the columns! Use `|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|` to remove the spacing

Comment: There's also a `\documentclass{...}` missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is from additional space added by `\tabcolsep`. You can, e.g., change your `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}` into `\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}`.

You can also set (locally) `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`.

(Alas, without the illustrating picture, as your images are not reachable.)

Comment: Damn, you were quicker ;-)  -- You could use `demo` mode of course