# Aligning Images and (Sub)tables in a Table

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying to adapt the answer given here by egreg:

[How to put a matrix of images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173820/how-to-put-a-matrix-of-images)

I want to have a table that has a histogram in one column and a corresponding subtable of descriptive statistics in the next column.

I have most of it in place but the histogram and table of descriptive statistics are not aligned. The histogram appears at the top of it's cell while the table of descriptive statistics appears at the bottom of it's cell.

1. How can I align the image of the histogram and the subtable?
2. Like the image I would like to add a caption underneath the table of descriptive statistics. (This should also be aligned with the caption under the image).

Thanks Baz

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
  {\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
 #1\\#2
\end{tabular}}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{1cm}}
    \hline
    Statistic & Value \\\hline
    Max & 2 \\
    min & 3 \\
    Mean & 2 \\
    Std & 3\\
    Skew & 2 \\
    Kurtosis & 3 \\
    Percent Positive & 100\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\\\
\hline
 \subf{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{1cm}}
    \hline
    Statistic & Value \\\hline
    Max & 2 \\
    min & 3 \\
    Mean & 2 \\
    Std & 3\\
    Skew & 2 \\
    Kurtosis & 3 \\
    Percent Positive & 100\\\hline
    \end{tabular}\\\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has to play a bit with the vertical position of images with respect to the baseline; `adjustbox` makes it quite easy:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
  {\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
 #1\\#2
\end{tabular}}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
    \hline
    Statistic & Value \\\hline
    Max & 2 \\
    min & 3 \\
    Mean & 2 \\
    Std & 3\\
    Skew & 2 \\
    Kurtosis & 3 \\
    Percent Positive & 100\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
 \subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
 {``iteraciones máximas \\ de BT''$=20$}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
    \hline
    Statistic & Value \\\hline
    Max & 2 \\
    min & 3 \\
    Mean & 2 \\
    Std & 3\\
    Skew & 2 \\
    Kurtosis & 3 \\
    Percent Positive & 100\\\hline
    \end{tabular}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure you want *any* of the vertical rules.

Comment: Hey egreg this is great! Is it possible to add a caption below the table of descriptive statistics aligned with the caption under the image? Also can you clarify what you mean when you say you are "not sure I want any of the vertical rules?"

Comment: @Bazman What caption to the descriptive statistics are you referring to?

Comment: So under the image you have the caption "interaciones..." I would like to be able to put some text under the each table for example saying  "Descriptive Statistics for Set 3" that is aligned with the text under the picture.

Comment: Ideally I would like to put a line between the image and the caption and also between the table and it's caption (again this should all be aligned)

Comment: @Bazman That's a much different thing. Can you give a text for a typical caption?

Comment: OK under the image which is a histogram I would have "Histogram of Steepener Results for Simulated Set 3" and under the table I would have "Descriptive Statistics for Simulated Set 3".

Comment: please also see my edit above...

Comment: Sorry please ignore comment about the edit, it does show a line under the image just not the table. But the table is no part of the subf function!

Comment: tnx for you help egreg!

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `\adjustbox{valign=T}{...}` from the `adjustbox` library or its environment form `\begin{adjustbox}{valign=T}...\end{adjustbox}` to align the figures and tables on the top.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox,array}

\newcommand{\Mtable}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{2cm}|p{1cm}}    
    \hline
    Statistic & Value \\\hline
    Max & 2 \\
    min & 3 \\
    Mean & 2 \\
    Std & 3\\
    Skew & 2 \\
    Kurtosis & 3 \\
    Percent Positive & 100\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{``Descriptive Statistics}\\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{for Simulated Set 3"} \\[-1ex] 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}\\
    ``Histogram of Steepener Results\\ for Simulated Set 3"
\end{tabular}}
&
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\Mtable}
\\ \hline
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}\\
    ``Histogram of Steepener Results\\ for Simulated Set 3"
\end{tabular}}
&
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\Mtable}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, with no need for `adjustbox`, you can use `\raisebox` from `graphicx` library. The idea is that images are naturally placed above the baseline while tables are naturally placed below the baseline. So, we simply raise the image as the negative of its height; this will make the image and the table start at the baseline and grow down.

Here is the `\raisebox` version:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}\\
    ``Histogram of Steepener Results\\ for Simulated Set 3"
\end{tabular}
&
\Mtable
\\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}\\
    ``Histogram of Steepener Results\\ for Simulated Set 3"
\end{tabular}
&
\Mtable
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```