# Add additional Caption/Change Linespacing in a Table

Tags: tables, graphics

This is related to a question I asked earlier:

[Aligning Images and (Sub)tables in a Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269097/aligning-images-and-subtables-in-a-table)

But I realised I will have to rearrange the way the data is being displayed so I will open a new question (this is definitely the final layout)

Q1.) Ideally I would like to be able to add a caption under each table of descriptive statistics as well, is this possible?

Q2.) I'd like to reduce the linespace used in the table of Descriptive Statistics? Is this possible?

Thanks

Baz

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
 {\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  #1\\ \hline #2
 \end{tabular}}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{Steep3Hist.eps}}
  {Simulated Subset 3 Data}
 &
\subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{Steep3Hist.eps}}
{Results for Simulated Subset 3 Data}\\
\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\end{tabular}

&
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
 \subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{Steep3Hist.eps}}
 {Results for Simulated Subset 3 Data}
&
 \subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{Steep3Hist.eps}}
{Results for Simulated Subset 3 Data}\\
\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results of Simulation Study for the Steepener Strategy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to replace `\#2` in the definition of `\subf` with `#2`.

Comment: tnx that part is sorted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> Q1.) Ideally I would like to be able to add a caption under each table of descriptive statistics as well, is this possible?
>
> Q2.) I'd like to reduce the linespace used in the table of Descriptive Statistics? Is this possible?

A1. You could add a table-related caption via a

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{<Caption Text>}\\
```

directive at the bottom of each of the four `tabular` environments.

A2. If you load the `setspace` package, you could issue the instruction `\setstretch{0.9}` *before* each of the four `tabular` environments.

The result of these suggestions applied to your code:

[image]

---

*Addendum*: To place the table-related captions in framed boxes, you could change the code block

```
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{<Caption Text>}\\
```

to

```
\addlinespace
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{<Caption Text>}\\
\hline
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%% Two additional packages
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro
\usepackage{setspace} % for '\setstretch' macro

\newcommand{\subf}[2]{%
 {\small\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  #1\\  \hline  \addlinespace #2 \\ \addlinespace % some more whitespace
 \end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=0.44\textwidth]{Steep3Hist.eps}}{Simulated Subset 3 Data}
 &
\subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=0.44\textwidth]{Steep3Hist.eps}}{Results for Simulated Subset 3 Data}\\
%\hline

\setstretch{0.9}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\
\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{First set of descriptive stats}\\
\end{tabular}
&
\setstretch{0.9}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second set of descriptive stats}\\
\end{tabular}\\
\hline

 \subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=0.44\textwidth]{Steep3Hist.eps}}{Results for Simulated Subset 3 Data}
&
 \subf{\includegraphics[valign=T,width=0.44\textwidth]{Steep3Hist.eps}}{Results for Simulated Subset 3 Data}\\
%\hline

\setstretch{0.9}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Third set of descriptive stats}\\
\end{tabular}
&
\setstretch{0.9}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
Statistic & Value \\\hline
Max & 2 \\
min & 3 \\
Mean & 2 \\
Std & 3\\
Skew & 2 \\
Kurtosis & 3 \\
Percent Positive & 100\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fourth set of descriptive stats}\\
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results of Simulation Study for the Steepener Strategy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's wonderful! is it possible to include line above and below each caption? I didn't ask for this but it would make it perfect!

Comment: @Bazman - I wouldn't add those lines. IMNSHO, such lines add nothing but visual clutter.

Comment: You are probably right but every other table/graph in the document is presented with a caption in a box I need to keep it consistent.

Comment: @Bazman - I've posted an addendum to my answer, in which I provide a suggestion for how you might go about placing the table captions in frame boxes.

Comment: Tnx for your help Mico!