# Figures and tables

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

in the thesis I am writing I am showing some plots (taken from external files) and some tables with the parameters I used to make the plots. I would like to place together each plot with its related table, so that it's easier for the reader. What can I do? I would like to avoid minipage

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you give more clear picture of your requirement along with the proper `MWE`....?

Comment: Sure. How can I insert in the same float a table and a figure together?

Comment: You should take at look at the `floatrow` package, in particular § 2.3.1, *Mixed row* in the documentation.

Comment: what have you tried? `\begin{figure}\includegraphics{...} \begin{tabular}{...}...\end{tabular} \caption{...} \endfigure}` would do what you ask.

Comment: I managed to put erything together in \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}. What can I do with captions? Because in this way the table figures as 'figure' instead of 'table'

Comment: The other idea would be to use two independent floats which are always placed in the same page

Comment: I thing that your question is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269097/.

Comment: as idea: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=150pt]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
$\longrightarrow$
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
4 & 9 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 5 & 7\\
\hline
8 & 1 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{The lo-shu magic square}
\label{fig:loshu}\end{figure}    \end{document}`

Comment: Probably also related: [Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850/134144)